# JQuery Submenu messed up (Weebly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, submenu

I am designing a website with the CMS of Weebly. Unfortunately Weebly doesn't support multilingual websites, so I had to do it with JQuery. I found a script at http://blessingsweb.weebly.com/1/post/2013/10/how-to-create-a-real-multilanguage-site-with-weebly.html and added it to my website. The script hides the German menus, when you are on the English website and hides the English menus, when you are on the German Website. Everything is working, apart from the submenu on the German website. Somehow the script changed the position of the submenu and also the direction of the slide from left to right, to top to bottom.

Demo: http://mop000.weebly.com/startseite.html as you can see, the submenu has some strange behaviour.

If you click on the flag, you will see that on the English site everything is working well.

What can I do?

Code added as languages-1.0.js-file:

```
function hideMenus() {
lang = language.toLowerCase();
console.log('LANG: ' + lang);

currentLang = null;
menus = jQuery(menuSelector + ' ul li').each(function(){
    menu = jQuery(this);
    a = menu.children('a');
    span = a.children('span');
    if (span.length == 0) text = a.html();
    else text = span.html();
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    if (langs[text] != null) {
        currentLang = langs[text].toLowerCase();
        if (currentLang == lang) { 
            //if this is the first page of this language, we set the logo to go to this page url
            jQuery('.wsite-logo a').attr('href', a.attr('href'));
        }
    }
    show = (currentLang == lang);
    if (show) menu.show(); else menu.hide();
  console.log('MENU:' + text + ' - current lang: ' + currentLang + ' - in langs '+ langs[text] + ' - '+ (show ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'));
});
}
```

Code added in the header (SEO) of the website:

```
<script src="/files/theme/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/files/theme/languages-1.0.js"></script>
<script>
langs = {          //everything in langs must be in lowercase
    'home': 'en',
    'startseite': 'de'
};
menuSelector = '#avmenu'; 
$(document).ready(function(){hideMenus()});
</script>
```

Code added on the German pages:

```
<script> language = 'de'; </script>
```

Code added on the English pages:

```
<script> language = 'en'; </script>
```

That's it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, you're loading jQuery twice.

Comment: You're right, thanks! Just removed it, but the problem is still there.

Comment: My guess is that because the language script changes the menu so much that the original bindings are disrupted. You may need to arrange things so that the language script runs before the menu init script.

Comment: Maybe. But as the script is in the header of the website, it should be loaded before the menu. Also the English menu is working well. It's just the second menu (the German one) that's not working properly.

Comment: It appears as though the English menu is the default, so the problem doesn't occur. Because the menu init script is embedded it runs first. Try embedding the language script in the page after it.

Comment: I think the problem is in the script. So can you maybe check the above posted code? (unfortunately I'm not very into Javascript)

Also: If I change the menu from vertical to horizontal, everything is working well. Just with my vertical menu, there's the problem with the submenu of the second language.

Comment: Where should I embed the language script? After what page?

Comment: I tried putting the language script now everywhere. Even at the footer-part of the pages (so the script is at the end of the website, as you can see in the source code) it's still not working. Any other ideas? Maybe something that could be changed in the language script?

Comment: @isherwood I had an idea: How about adding another script, that moves the messed up menu back to it's place and changes the slide direction?

I already figured out how to change the position back to the default value. But how can I change the slide direction back to "from left to right"?

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".wsite-menu-wrap").css({
          "padding": "0px",
          "margin-left": "220px",
          "margin-top": "-42px"
       });
    });

Comment: I suggested that embed the language script in the page (just like the menu script). You're still linking it, which makes it load after the menu script. You probably want it loading before the menu script. You shouldn't have to write code to fix these problems. Those are just complicating things.

Comment: Ok, now I got what you said. I embedded the language script now before the menu script, but it's still not working.

Is the menu script really embedded? I thought that all the scripts concerning the CMS are linked to this file http://cdn2.editmysite.com/js/site/main.js?buildTime=1391637377

Comment: I found a interesting part of code in the main.js file, which I think is responsible to decide whether the submenu should be slid vertical or horizontal.

Here is the part of the code: http://pastebin.com/S09wVxHK

I don't really understand the code, but I think it checks the width or something to decide whether the submenu should be slid horizontal or vertical. So my suspicion: The language.js messes up the positioning and the size of the menu and so the main.js is not able any more to slide it correctly.

What do you think?